# What is the rate limit of FourSquare's multi requests endpoint?

Tags: foursquare

I want to use the following FourSquare api: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/multi.
I have the following two questions:

1. In the response header, I get X-RateLimit-Remaining key and it seems
   that the requests are counted one even if I batched more requests.
   Is it correct?
2. In the api description, I read that these requests accept GET and POST methods, as well. If I use GET method then the X-RateLimit-Limit (the maximum number of requests per hour) returns 5000, however, if I use POST method then its value is 500. Why? Is it deliberate or a mistake?

Comment: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits

Comment: I use batched requests to the /venue/* endpoint with the /multi endpoint. For example: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/multi?requests=/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3,/venues/4eb7b9400aaf1abee0404a20. If I use GET method then the X-RateLimit-Limit is 5000; if I use POST method then the X-RateLimit-Limit is 500. The documentation you posted does not answer this question.

Comment: From the documentation, you will see the /venues only supports GET requests. /venues is also a userless request, which grants you 5000 hits/hour. I'm guessing that when you do a GET request to /multi, it assumes a userless request (no auth). /venues doesn't support POST, so when you do a POST to /multi, my next guess is that that endpoint stops assuming a userless request, which then drops your rate limit to 500 per hour. They also assume when you are using POST you are sending/receiving large amounts of data, and they may limit the rate for this reason too.